# Is it possible to make Linux to autocompile my LaTeX-document

Tags: compiling, latex

Is it possible to do the following in Linux? I'm writing a particular LaTeX-file using Nano. I would like to have my document compiled every time I save my document, i.e. I press F3.

Comment: This question is already covered on tex.sx, which is probably a better place for this. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/3406. Personally, I use scons on the command line, plus auctex from inside emacs, but e.g. latexmk seems quite popular.

Comment: This could be accomplished by a couple mechanisms: Have nano run a command or script every time you save a latex document, or have a program watch your files and run a command or script everytime a latex document is updated. You might want to investigate those routes. The first question would be appropriate to ask on, say, the nano mailing list, while the second question might be better asked here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on [Tex Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com)...

Comment: @jasonwryan, how would it be off-topic, it's asking about a Linux way to perform some action upon a Unix editor saving a file.

Comment: ??? Why the downvotes and close votes on this question? It's perfectly reasonable and on-topic. The fact that it may be on-topic elsewhere doesn't affect this.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Given there is a Tex Exchange, I thought it best asked there...

Comment: I don't know what it is with LaTeX in particular that puts people in "belongs on tex.se" mode as soon as they see it, regardless of the actual question, but this keeps coming up. The question wants nano to run a program every time they hit F3; the fact that that program is `latex` is irrelevant